# JavaScript game: changing the angle of an object

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use JavaScript to rotate an object. When it changes direction, I just add or subtract from the `Angle` value.

```
Angle += 0.1;
```

or

```
Angle -= 0.1;
```

My problem is when the object does a complete rotation it continues adding to it, instead of starting from 0 again.

I'm working in radians but will accept an answer using degrees too.

Comment: Check out the [Modulus Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators)!

Comment: thanks mate, should i delete my question?

Comment: If you want to you can, but I think it's a good question- maybe someone else can benefit from it! Here, let me write up a legitimate answer for you.

Comment: cheers, from your link it looks like you can use % to set limits, maybe:  angle = angle % 360

Comment: You're a quick study!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a great question!

If you want to keep Angle confined to 360 degrees you can simply say (in radians):

```
Angle = Angle % (2*pi);
```

The [modulus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) is useful for all sorts of things, but this is a great example of why it's so commonly used in development.

Comment: Glad I could help, I hope you have a fantastic day!